# Selenium with python detection limiting the amount of result in the webpage

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on the code to crawl ITA matrix website(https://matrix.itasoftware.com/) and automate the process of searching fares for a given origin and destination.I am using chrome webdriver. My code is working fine and is able to get all the fare details that are available for a given search. The issue i am facing is that , the results(list of fares) obtained by the selenium operated browser is less when compared with the results that are obtained by me manually operating the browser. I doubt that ITA website has some mechanism to detect the automation with selenium and is thus restricting the content of the results displayed.
Is my doubt a valid scenario? if yes, then is there any way i can bypass the detection and get all the results? I have also attached some screen shot showing the difference in the results.
Any suggestions will be most appreciated and thanks in advance.

Below is the code that is used.

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3845.84 Safari/537.35"')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
chrome_options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
chrome_options.add_argument('--incognito')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-plugins-discovery')
chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Program Files\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.delete_all_cookies()
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://matrix.itasoftware.com/")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 80)

# clicking on one-way tab
try :
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(),'One-way')]"))).click()
except TimeoutException as e:
    print('one-way tab could not be found')
    print(e)
except Exception as e:
    print('exception occured when trying to click on one-way tab')
    print(e)

# entering the origin 
try:
    origin_input = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="searchPanel-0"]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/input')))
    origin_input.send_keys(origin)
    time.sleep(2)

    origin_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(), "KHI")]').click()

except TimeoutException as e:
    print('exception occured when inputing origin')
    print(e)

# entering the destination
try:
    destination_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchPanel-0"]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div/input')
    destination_input.send_keys(destination)
    time.sleep(2)

    origin_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(), "JED")]').click()

except NoSuchElementException as e:
    print('exception occured when inputing destination')
    print(e)


# entering the departure date
try:
    date_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchPanel-0"]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div[2]/div/div/div[9]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/input')
    date_input.send_keys(dep_date)
    time.sleep(1)
except NoSuchElementException as e:
    print('exception occured when inputing dep date')
    print(e)

# clicking the search button
try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@id="searchButton-0"]').click()
except NoSuchElementException as e:
    print('could not find the search button')
    print(e)
```

[image: Manual search result]
[image: selenium search result]

Comment: You need to share your code as well and mentioned how many records you are after for a given search.

Comment: @vickee You need to update the question with the relevant HTML, code trials and errors (if any)

Comment: Hi @KunduK  thank you for your responses. I have added the code snippet that i used and also have attached the screen shots showing the difference in the results. Please let me know if any further details are needed.We can see that the number of airlines that are being operated itself varies hugely in both cases.

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB i am not getting any kind of error , the execution is fine , but the issue is that i am not able to retrieve all the data.I have added some relevant info to the question. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: @vickee :  It seems deliberately browser is detected.Sorry I have to disappoint you.Sorry I can't help you.

Comment: @KunduK Thank you for taking the time to have a look.

Comment: @vickee I think the difference in results is due to putting the browser in incognito mode.  Try searching manually in incognito mode and see if get the same results. From the screen shot you posted, it looks like you are not incognito mode when you search manually.

Comment: @Jortega I initially tried in normal browser only and was facing the same issue. I then moved to incognito mode hoping it would help. So i don't think that is the cause for the issue.